# nginx is redirecting the wrong site

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have Debian 10 and nginx. I have 2 sites defined in /etc/nginx/sites-available and /etc/nginx/sites-enabled. One site uses http and the other uses https. nginx keeps redirecting the http site to the https site, and I can't figure out why. The http site conf file:

```
server {


listen 80;
    server_name reporting;

    root /var/www/reporting;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    proxy_buffer_size   128k;
    proxy_buffers   4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_param ALL_FILES_PATH /var/www/blahblah;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
}
```

the https site conf file:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains" ;
    server_name my_https_server;
    root /var/www/my_https_server/htdocs;
    
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/my.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers '<ciphers here>';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    proxy_buffer_size   128k;
    proxy_buffers   4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            #
            #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

            fastcgi_param ALL_FILES_PATH /var/www/blahblah;
            fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file=/var/www/my_auth_file.php";

            fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
}
```

If I put

```
http://reporting/index.php
```

in my browser it appears to be applying the

```
auto_prepend_file=/var/www/my_auth_file.php
```

I get redirected to:

```
https://reporting:80/login_to_site.php
```

which exists in my_auth_file.php.

I don't understand why nginx is allowing stuff from one site's config to affect a different site. How can I fully separate these sites so the https's "auto_prepend_file..." part doesn't interfere with the http site?

If I disable the https site by deleting the symlink in /etc/nginx/sites_enabled, the redirect does not happen, but I would like to be able to get to both sites.

**output of nginx -T **

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        #ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
# 
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-auth-pam.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_auth_pam_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-dav-ext.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_dav_ext_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-echo.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_echo_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-subs-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_subs_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-upstream-fair.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_upstream_fair_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite_master:

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains" ;
        server_name mysite-master;
        root /var/www/mysite_master_0/htdocs;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/all.mysite.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/all.mysite.com.key;
   
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        proxy_buffer_size   128k;
        proxy_buffers   4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

                # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            
            
            
                        fastcgi_param ALL_FILES_PATH /var/www/mysite_master_0;
                        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file=/var/www/mysite_master_0/htdocs/authorization/auth.inc.php";

                        # fastcgi_index index.php;
                        fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            }

        }

}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf:

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params:
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/reporting:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name reporting;

    root /var/www/reporting;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    proxy_buffer_size   128k;
    proxy_buffers   4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_param ALL_FILES_PATH /var/www/blahblah;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the output of the command `nginx  -T`. Do not obfuscate anything.

Comment: Are the two domains related? Is one a subdomain of the other?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have added the output.

Comment: @RichardSmith They are 2 completely separate sites.

Comment: Nginx is not redirecting from `http` to `https`, so either the browser is doing it or the PHP script is doing it. Use `curl -I` to test the `http` site without using a browser, so see it the server is responding as expected.

Comment: You have Strict-Transport-Security set.  Once this has been fed to a browser, ALL accesses on that domain will be sent as https.   You may check this using private/incognito mode, or curl as suggested by @RichardSmith

Comment: I suspected that the fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file=/var/www/mysite_master_0/htdocs/authorization/auth.inc.php"; line was redirecting the user. I'm confused because that line is in the conf file for the ssl site, which seems like it should be completely separate from the conf file for the http site. Are you saying the Strict-Transport-Security setting in the "mysite_master" file is overriding  the "reporting" file?

Comment: I did some additional testing and it's definitely the auto_prepend_file that's redirecting the user. However, how can a line in one nginx conf file that is for one website include the "fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE" for a /completely different site/? Is there no way to restrict the Strict-Transport-Security to only the one site?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than a complete fix. It's not the best solution but it's good enough. I created some bash scripts that basically delete the files in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled and "activate" only 1 site at a time. Here is an example of "activate_reporting":

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/reporting /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/reporting
sudo service nginx stop
sudo service php7.3-fpm stop
sudo service php7.3-fpm start
sudo service nginx start
```

So if I want to access the reporting site I just run that. I can only have 1 site active at once, but at least I can access them.